# Insert CSV data in django models, empty values

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, type-conversion

I have CSV data which I add as django models each line after another.

```
for row in reader:
    elm, created_elm = Elm.objects.get_or_create(name=row[0], year=int(row[1]), power=int(row[2]))
```

Unlucky, in some cases row[1] is empty (in example, when csv row looks like:

> Name,,1300

I get error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

How can I convert '' value to int 0 and then insert it to the database?

Answer (score 2):

I've googled and it may be even shorter:

```
year = row[1] or 0
```

We can close the question.

Comment: but still you cant convert the row[1] right . you need to convert it to integer

Answer (score 0):

just give `year=int(row[1]) if row[1] else 0`

```
elm, created_elm = Elm.objects.get_or_create(name=row[0], year=int(row[1]) if row[1] else 0, power=int(row[2]))
```